# CSS - images not showing properly

Tags: html, css, image, styles

Here is the problem. I have a footer which has absolute position to the bottom:

```
  .footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato; 
}
```

From here on I add image as .footerimage:

```
.footerfacebook{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3.54%;
    left: 3%;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Here is the html code for the image:

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/aaster23" target="_blank"><img class="footerfacebook" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/facebook_logos/facebook_logos_PNG19754.png"></a>
```

The problem is that the image doesn't have width of 90px and height of 70px, here are the real width and height: 124:124
[image]

The problem is that it moves the footer up and there is space under it.
Thanks for the help :)!

Comment: you've used the wrong class? (css is `footerimage`, img tag has `footerfacebook`)

Comment: My bad I've edited the code, the class i use is footerfacebook

Comment: Ah it's because you add 2 rem padding, remove that and your image will revert to 60 x 60

Comment: try removing the padding from `.footerfacebook`

Comment: Thanks @Pete! It worked :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Have a look at box-sizing css property - it may help you with these types of issues in future